# Get types from NOT loaded assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, silverlight-5.0

I need to enumerate types in a certain namespace which physically lies in a Silverlight dll. But I have to do it on a server (asp.net app).

I have xap file, I can read it with zip and get the dll I need.

However I want not to load that assembly in memory (I think it might not get loaded as it is Silverlight app) also as long as I remember loaded assembly cannot be unloaded (dont want to junk server memory just to get few strings).

Any ideas?

**EDIT** : ReflectionOnlyLoad does not work for Silverlight assembly.. Any other ideas?

Comment: Maybe it's just odd wording here, but you are aware that namespaces and assemblies aren't in a 1-1 relationship, aren't you?

Comment: the question doesnt anyhow implies 1-1..

Comment: _"loaded assembly cannot be unloaded"_ - a loaded assembly can be unloaded if you loaded it in a child `AppDomain` first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use:

```
Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad(string assemblyString)
```

This will load the assembly (without depencies) in a special context. You can not execute any methods. You can unload this assembly, without unloading the complete AppDomain.

[MSDN: Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0et80c7k.aspx)

Comment: Got: Could not load file or assembly 'blabla.dll' or one of its dependencies. The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)

Comment: deleted it.. it was someth like:                 string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/ClientBin/1/blabla.dll");
Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad(path);

Comment: P.S. I unzipped xap into ClientBin/1 by hand - so all dlls with all dependencies were there.... Server project is .net 4 and silverlight app is SL5. both were built as AnyCPU... not sure what else is wrong. Server project is 32-bit I am sure of it...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Mono.Cecil](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil) to inspect Silverlight assemblies (or different .NET runtime assemblies) from your .NET application.

Answer (score 0):

Try ReflectionOnlyLoad. You can pass either a string (path to assembly file) or byte[] (COFF image of assembly - should be the resultant byte[] you get from unzipping the assembly).

Comment: Is that going to work on a silverlight assembly from normal. Net?

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to load it, though you are going to need to load it into silverlight and will need silverlight code to do the enumeration.  The plus side is that since you will need to load it through COM interop it should get cleaned up when you tear down the SL instance.